# Best way to tune up synchronization of nested hashmap

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap, nested

I stumbled upon many examples on how to synchronize hashmap or how to use concurrent collections. But i am wondering what is the best way to tune up synchronization of structure similar to this, because it is a nested map:

```
Map<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> map = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>>();
```

Note: Second level, and third level maps are mostly updated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is too vague. How are you using this structure? What do you want to "tune up" about it?

Comment: Not obvious what you want to do. Not obvious what access patterns are. Not obvious at all what the question is.

Comment: Well i was wondering, should i wrap whole map with Collections.SynchronizedMap() or should i use ConcurrentHashMap for all map instances, or something else?

Comment: It really depends on how exactly you intend to use. No way we can answer like this.

Comment: Sorry for being not so clear. For example if outer hashmap is instance of ConcurrentHashMap, and second and third maps are regular HashMap instances. If i retrieve second map by key andtry to modify it, is it going to be thread safe?

Comment: No. Most definitely not. The real question you have to ask yourself is why you have a nested map rather than a composite key.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarifications about this question on comments:

1) nested maps won't be thread-safe

2) If you need to do any insert/delete/update operations, you need to do them in a threadsafe way

3) You will need a concurrentHashMap for each layer of nesting that can be simultaneously worked upon by more than one threads.

Maybe you should try to write code based on the above understanding for a single-map and then try to extend that to further layers.

On a different note, what exactly is this data structure going to be used in? You should probably also consider finding ways to simplify it.